# Delete the first word in a "contentEditable" element will break Angular 6 NgFor Binding

Tags: html, angular

```
  <div 
    class="transcript-snippet__content__body__sentance"
    [contentEditable]="true">
    <span *ngFor="let word of words; let i = index;"

      class="transcript-snippet__content__body__word">{{word.displayWord}}</span>
  </div>
```

By using the above template, the HTML is generated as :

```
 <div _ngcontent-c18=""
  class="transcript-snippet__content__body__sentance ng-star-inserted"
  contenteditable="true">
  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object",
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-track-by": "function (index, word) {\n     "
}-->
  <span _ngcontent-c18=""
    class="transcript-snippet__content__body__word ng-star-inserted"
    key="0">Hello </span>
  <span _ngcontent-c18=""
    class="transcript-snippet__content__body__word ng-star-inserted"
    key="1">World </span>
  <span _ngcontent-c18=""
    class="transcript-snippet__content__body__word ng-star-inserted"
    key="2">ContentEditable</span>
  <span _ngcontent-c18=""
    class="transcript-snippet__content__body__word ng-star-inserted"
    key="3">.</span>
</div>
```

If I delete|cut the first character 'H' in 'Hello', the `<!--bindings ... -->` will be removed. All following Template logic will be blocked. 
Is there a way to work around it? Can we prevent breaking the binding?

Comment: Sorry, can you be more precise, please? How do you remove the 'H' and why should this break the binding?

Answer (score 0):

In the contentEditable element, if we try to delete the first 'Span' element, edit the first 'Span' element with empty spaces, or overwrite the whole 'Span' element (such as the paste), the  tags may be deleted. Then the Angular Logic breaks.